# Lambda Calculus in Rewriting systems

Tags: turing-machines, lambda-calculus, turing-completeness, term-rewriting

How to do or implement [Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) in a [Rewriting systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting)?

Rewriting systems are Turing complete.

But I can't figure out how to do lambda calculus or functions with them.

Comment: As an aside to Martin's excellent answer, *simulating* the $\lambda$-calculus with rewrite systems (which is all that is implied by the statement "Turing complete") is actually quite simple: rewrite systems are essentially like ML or Haskell with only *top-level* functions and pattern matching (no lambdas or maps). However you would write a $\lambda$-calculus simulator in those languages probably carries over to rewrite systems as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See also this question: ["How is Lambda Calculus a specific type of Term Writing system?"](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/36090/how-is-lambda-calculus-a-specific-type-of-term-writing-system).

Term rewriting, as introduced in (1), and described in e.g. (2), is a first-order system that cannot handle binding. Consider the $map$ function.

$$
  \begin{array}{lcl}
  map(f, []) &\rightarrow& [] \\
  map(f, cons(x, l)) &\rightarrow& cons( f\ x, map\ f\ l) 
  \end{array}
  $$

The problem is that $f$ is used both as a variable and a function
  symbol, which is not permitted by first-order term-rewriting system.

This lead to *higher-order rewriting*, see e.g (3) for an overview. Another approach to unification of term-rewriting with the $\lambda$-calculus is
the *rewriting calculus* (4). Yet another approach  towards rewriting with binders -- arguably the most modern -- is *nominal rewriting* (5).

---

1. D. E. Knuth, P. Bendix, [Simple Word Problems in Universal Algebras](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/don-knuth/knuth-bendix.pdf).
2. F. Baader, T. Nipkow, [Term Rewriting and All That](https://www21.in.tum.de/~nipkow/TRaAT/).
3. T. Nipkow, C. Prehofer, [Higher-Order Rewriting and Equational Reasoning](https://www21.in.tum.de/~nipkow/pubs/ded-book.html).
4. H. Cirstea, C. Kirchner, [Introduction to the rewriting calculus.](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00072840/document)
5. M. Fernandez, M. J. Gabbay, [Nominal Rewriting](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540106001635).